# Why is the near-field radius of a small antenna lambda/2PI?

Tags: antenna, near-field

If I have a small antenna, the near-field is said to extend to \$\frac\lambda{2\pi}\$:

> The outer boundary of the reactive near-field region is commonly
> considered to be a distance of \${\textstyle {\frac {1}{2\pi }}}\$ times  the wavelength (i.e., \${\textstyle {\frac {\lambda }{2\pi }}}\$ or approximately 0.159λ) from the antenna surface.

From
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near_and_far_field.

I do not understand why the distance is \$\frac\lambda{2\pi}\$, I know the concept of far-field is not clear cut, but I still want to understand where this distance comes from. All literature I can find gloss over this, only referring to the reactive field becoming destructive.

The best **speculative**, handwavy explanation I can come up with is by looking at the high impedance electric field close to an antenna made up of two oposite point charges. In my mind, changes to the electric field propagate along the field lines with a speed of c. The electric field will form a roughly circular loop, tangent with the two charges, with circumference \$O=\pi D\$ meters. For the field to loop back and become destructive, it would have to travel \$O=\frac\lambda{2}\$ meters (I.e. 180 degrees shifted). So the near field will, by this definition, extend to the diameter of this circle, given by \$\frac\lambda{2}=\pi D\$ hence \$D=\frac\lambda{2\pi}\$.

Is this what's going on, or am I barking up the wrong tree here?

Comment: Where did the near-field radius formula come from. Please add a link so that everyone is on the same page.

Comment: [This calculator](https://www.everythingrf.com/rf-calculators/antenna-near-field-distance-calculator) uses a different formula. It's all a bit hit and miss with antennas so I wouldn't particularly worry about it. There is no hard and fast rule in effect. [This site](https://www.giangrandi.org/electronics/anttool/regions.shtml) agrees. So does [this site](https://www.antenna-theory.com/basics/fieldRegions.php)

Comment: That formula is for a large antenna. Yes, I know it's not clear cut, but the λ/2π comes up so much I still want to understand how it was arrived at, regardless of its physical significance.

Comment: Good luck in your quest!

Comment: When making antenna measurements with a near field scanner, near field is taken as being within a wavelength or two of the antenna element, not a small fraction of the wavelength.  I guess that would be the radiating new field region mention in one of Andy's links.  I guess the conclusion is that the term "near field" by itself is a bit ambiguous.